# How is $\boldsymbol{v} \stackrel{q}{\otimes} \boldsymbol{v}$, the tensorial product of a vector by itself repeated $q$ times, is defined?

Tags: real-analysis, tensor-products, tensors, products, kronecker-product

The tensorial product of a vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ by itself is given as $\boldsymbol{v}  \otimes \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{v}^\mathrm{T}$ which is a tensor of dimension 2. While i was reading a research paper (Below Eq (21) in [Arxiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.02464.pdf)), the authors defined $\boldsymbol{v} \stackrel{q}{\otimes} \boldsymbol{v}$ with $q \ge 2$. How this can actually be obtained?

Consider for instance as an example $\boldsymbol{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$ and $q \in \{2, 3\}$.

Thank you

Comment: $(v\otimes v)_{ij}=v_iv_j$, $(v\otimes v\otimes v)_{ijk}=v_iv_jv_k$, $(v\otimes v\otimes v\otimes v)_{ijkl}=v_iv_jv_kv_l$, ...

Comment: The obvious choice would be what Surb said, though you should probably state the name of the paper and give a link if possible so that people can check if its actually right

Comment: @Surb thanks! Please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Here is the paper (https://journals.aps.org/prfluids/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevFluids.4.124204) below Eq. (21). The article should also be freely available on arxiv.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Here is the arxiv version(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.02464.pdf). The tensorial product of a vector $\boldsymbol{r}_k$ by itself is defined below Eq. (21). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of examples for $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)\in\Bbb R^n$ may help.

$$(v\otimes v)_{i,j} = v_iv_j \qquad \forall i,j =1,\ldots,n$$
$$(v\otimes v\otimes v)_{i,j,k} = v_iv_jv_k \qquad \forall i,j,k =1,\ldots,n$$
$$(v\otimes v\otimes v\otimes v)_{i,j,k,l} = v_iv_jv_kv_l \qquad \forall i,j,k,l =1,\ldots,n$$
Generally,
$$(v\overset{q}\otimes v)_{i_1,\ldots,i_q} = \prod_{s=1}^qv_{i_s}\qquad \forall i_1,\ldots,i_q =1,\ldots,n$$

Comment: Side note: Another notation commonly used in the numerical linear algebra tensor community for the same object is $v^{\otimes q}$.

Comment: I might be a good idea to mention how to derive this equations, namely by using multilinearity. For example:$$v\otimes v=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nv_ie_i\right)\otimes\left(\sum_{j=1}^nv_je_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(v_iv_j)(e_i\otimes e_j)$$